# MySQL Selecting records by multiple IDs with LIMIT per each ID 4

Tags: php

I'm stuck with query. The scenario is like this: - I need to select max 4 product_name for each category. - I'm using this query but it doesn't work the way I need -each cat_id with product_name limit 4

the result will contain 4 lines from the whole query output.

```
   $sql_course = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id IN('".$brand_filter."') ORDER BY cat_id LIMIT 4";
```

i want this

```
cat_id1- product1
cat_id1- product2
cat_id1- product3
cat_id1- product4

cat_id2- product5
cat_id2- product6
cat_id2- product7
cat_id2- product8
```

Comment: you want to also get cat_id? in the result

Comment: yes cat_id also

Comment: what is your current output can you add a snapshot in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038414/how-can-i-get-5-records-for-each-category-with-one-select-in-mysql

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011071/display-last-2-entries-in-each-category-from-a-mysql-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get 5 records for each 'category' with one select in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038414/how-can-i-get-5-records-for-each-category-with-one-select-in-mysql)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038414/how-can-i-get-5-records-for-each-category-with-one-select-in-mysql you just need to change the query, other than that both are same requirement

Answer (score 0):

Limit is affecting your output cause it only bring four records.

Comment: i want each id with 4 record

Comment: That's because you are using Limit on the entire query.

Comment: I will suggest you to fetch all records and then show only 4 for each category using your php logic otherwise you will have to write a custom function in Mysql for this.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $sql_course = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE cat_id IN('".$brand_filter."') GROUP BY cat_id ORDER BY cat_id LIMIT 4";
```

i guess this will work, try and check the result.

Comment: $sql_course = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE CAT_ID IN(SELECT DISTINCT CAT_ID FROM PRODUCT) GROUP BY  CAT_ID ORDER BY CAT_ID LIMIT 4";